# Regexp for certain character to end of line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string

```
"So on and so forth $5.99"
```

I would like to extract everything after the `$` until the end of the line.

`/$` finds the character `$`. How do I select the rest of the string? I know it's something `\z` but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: (1) **`/$` finds the character `$`**: No, it does not. (2) **I know it's something `\z`**: No, it is not.

Comment: Do you want to match to the end of line or the end of string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regexp `$` represents the end of the line.
So in your case you need `\$.*$`  To include your escaped `$` and everything `(.*)` up until the end of the line `$`.

Answer (score 2):

No, `/$` does not match that character. You need to escape it `\` to match a literal.

```
string = "So on and so forth $5.99"
result = string.match(/\$(.*)$/)
puts result[1] #=> "5.99"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture everything after the $, you'll want:

```
/\$(.*)\z/
```

See http://rubular.com/r/T4fR1SEl3j